# How to insert a string into a numpy list every nth index?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

Let's say i have a list like this one:

```
b = np.array(['a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c'])
```

and i wanted to insert this character at every 17th position '\n':

```
np.insert(b,b[::16],'\n')
```

why do i get this error message and how would be a corect way to do this?

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second argument for `np.insert` should be the index to place the values, you can try:

```
n = 3
np.insert(b, range(n, len(b), n), "\n") 

# array(['a', 'b', 'c', '\n', 'a', 'b', 'c', '\n', 'a', 'b', 'c', '\n', 'a',
#        'b', 'c'], 
#       dtype='<U1')
```

Comment: Nice, thank you! I kinda misread numpy.insert needing a slice of indices ;)